# Google Maps - Shortest route between two points using given polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been developing a prototype of a webpage about public transport for my city. It's the typical page where you can enter an origin and a destiny address and the page shows which bus lines you should take for moving through de city.

I've encountered a big problem: from point A to point B there is a bus line in the same travel-direction (represented with a polyline). I find the best bus line calculating the lowest distance between the points and the polyline(s). Here everything is fine, BUT when I want go from point B to point A (same points of before), there is no bus line in that direction, however the page will keep suggesting the bus line of before.

In brief, the bus go just in one way between these points, but a drawed polyline don't have direction, so it works in both cases (A to B and B to A).

There is a way to consider the direction A-B of a polyline?

I've been thinking in deal with this as a shortest route between nodes problem, with big costs in directions where the bus lines are not supposed to go. But also I think, is a little to much for this. What do you think?

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

An idea is use the path index of the polyline, and consider a route (polyline) between origin and destiny only if the path index grows between these points.

I use [v3_BdccGeo.js](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/) to get the min-distance between point and polyline, but this function doesn't return the closest point, only the distance. In case I could find the closest point, it could also not belong to path index, but to a polyline segment (in this case I can't get the index of the point in polylines path).

If something needs to be clarify, just say it. Thanks in advance

**Update 2:**

Solved! Finally I made that of the check polyline's index, the v3_BdccGeo.js DOES return the index that I need.

Comment: Polylines do have direction: from A to B. Are you using the Directions methods of the API? If not, this doesn't have much to do with Google Maps: it's a route-finding exercise which you display on a map *after you have found the route*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and apology for the late answer. No, I don't use the Directions methods, I take two address, I turn them into coordenates and with a function I find which polyline is the closest to these two points. I have these polylines defined in the code.